# Kinect Fusion V2 export mesh with color as a STL or OBJ file

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I am using the Kinect V2 and the Kinect Fusion Explorer V2 to record 3D scans. I am recording the color too, but if I am trying to export the mesh with color as a STL or OBJ file the mesh has no color. Only if I export a PLY file the mesh has a color. I need a STL file or a OBJ file and I think the MTL file is missing. I can't find anything in the Kinect documentation that only the PLY file contains color.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **3D Scan** from the Windows Store, extensions are **.3mf** and are Colour, or write your own:

Might be worth your time checking out the Kinect Fusion Example in the SDK: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=44561

```
ColorMesh mesh = null;

Win32.SaveFileDialog dialog = new Win32.SaveFileDialog();

if (true == this.objFormat.IsChecked)
{
dialog.FileName = "MeshedReconstruction.obj";
dialog.Filter = "OBJ Mesh Files|*.obj|All Files|*.*";
}

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(dialog.FileName))
{
// Default to flip Y,Z coordinates on save
KinectFusionHelper.SaveAsciiObjMesh(mesh, writer, true);
}
```

In the Helper Class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Save mesh in ASCII WaveFront .OBJ file
/// </summary>
/// <param name="mesh">Calculated mesh object</param>
/// <param name="writer">The text writer</param>
/// <param name="flipAxes">Flag to determine whether the Y and Z values are flipped on save,
/// default should be true.</param>
public static void SaveAsciiObjMesh(ColorMesh mesh, TextWriter writer, bool flipAxes)
{
if (null == mesh || null == writer)
{
return;
}

var vertices = mesh.GetVertices();
var normals = mesh.GetNormals();
var indices = mesh.GetTriangleIndexes();

// Check mesh arguments
if (0 == vertices.Count || 0 != vertices.Count % 3 || vertices.Count != indices.Count)
{
throw new ArgumentException(Properties.Resources.InvalidMeshArgument);
}

// Write the header lines
writer.WriteLine("#");
writer.WriteLine("# OBJ file created by Microsoft Kinect Fusion");
writer.WriteLine("#");

// Sequentially write the 3 vertices of the triangle, for each triangle
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count; i++)
{
var vertex = vertices[i];

string vertexString = "v " + vertex.X.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " ";

if (flipAxes)
{
vertexString += (-vertex.Y).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + (-vertex.Z).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
else
{
vertexString += vertex.Y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + vertex.Z.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

writer.WriteLine(vertexString);
}

// Sequentially write the 3 normals of the triangle, for each triangle
for (int i = 0; i < normals.Count; i++)
{
var normal = normals[i];

string normalString = "vn " + normal.X.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " ";

if (flipAxes)
{
normalString += (-normal.Y).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + (-normal.Z).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
else
{
normalString += normal.Y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + normal.Z.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

writer.WriteLine(normalString);
}

// Sequentially write the 3 vertex indices of the triangle face, for each triangle
// Note this is typically 1-indexed in an OBJ file when using absolute referencing!
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Count / 3; i++)
{
string baseIndex0 = ((i * 3) + 1).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string baseIndex1 = ((i * 3) + 2).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string baseIndex2 = ((i * 3) + 3).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string faceString = "f " + baseIndex0 + "//" + baseIndex0 + " " + baseIndex1 + "//" + baseIndex1 + " " + baseIndex2 + "//" + baseIndex2;
writer.WriteLine(faceString);
}
}
```

You can see, the .OBJ Vertex Colour's are not included by default - you need to include Vertex Colour information for ths .OBJ in the .MTL file.

```
mesh.VertexColors;
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.fusion.mesh.vertexcolors.aspx

**batman.OBJ** Header:

```
mtllib batman.mtl
```

which may contain some data like:

```
# 
# 

newmtl batman
Ns 96.078431
Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.100000 0.100000 0.100000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000

...
```

Maybe check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn435687.aspx for some more info on this.